# javascript error when downloading pdf file (blob)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using this approach for downloading a pdf file from server (laravel 8 (api sanctum) + vue 3)

In the vue component I have this function that downloads the file

```
const onDownloadDocument = (id) => {           
   axios.post('/api/document/download', {id: id},{
     responseType: 'blob'
   }).then(response => {
     let filename = response.headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]               
     dLink.value.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
     dLink.value.setAttribute('download',filename)
     dLink.value.click()
   }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
   })
```

where dLink is a link ref

```
const dLink = ref(null)
```

in template:

```
<a ref="dLink"/>
```

It works this approach until today.... after I updated the project (composer update and npm update)

Now when click to download the file (call the onDownloadDocument function) I get an error:

```
contract.js:1049 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'responseType')
```

Any idea why ?

The api backend return the file blob

```
return Storage::download($document->filename);
```

Comment: What is `contract.js:1049`? The stack trace will tell you exactly what piece of code is causing the problem.

Comment: @miken32 it's an if `if (error.request.responseType === 'blob' && error.response.data instanceof Blob && error.response.data.type && error.response.data.type.toLowerCase().indexOf('json') !== -1)` that I am using in error catch .... now I commented all the code from  catch error and set only console.log(error) and get `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'href')` wihich is pointing on this line `dLink.value.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);`

Comment: are you sure you want to use dLink in your template ? You don't need to attach to a "real" <a> tag. Just creating one on the fly is enough.

Comment: @jeremycastelli what do you mean on the fly ? can you show me an example ?

Comment: Code is not pretty in comment, I create an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to create a blob and put your response in it,

And as I said in my comment you don't need to attach to a real anchor tag, you can just create an element, attach it to the body, simulate the click and remove it immediately

```
const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'})
if (window.navigator['msSaveOrOpenBlob']) {
    window.navigator['msSaveBlob'](blob, filename)
}
else {
    const elem = window.document.createElement('a')
    elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    elem.download = filename
    document.body.appendChild(elem)
    elem.click()
    document.body.removeChild(elem)
}
```

Comment: I get it ... but this is the reason that I avoided the document (dom). In setup I have a reference document `const document = ref({})` and it's a little bit complicated for this component to rename it to another. It's getting an error now `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')` because it tries to use the document model. Is there a way how can I use document (dom) instead of document (model ref) ?

Comment: window.document ?

Comment: yup..... forgot about window :-) now it works

Comment: great ! Glad it works

Comment: I noticed now that the doc is downloaded ... but `File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported` it does not open. It seems like it is a corrupt file. Any idea ?

Comment: fixed `const elem = window.document.createElement('a')
                elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
                elem.setAttribute('download',filename)
                elem.click()
`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, specify to axios that you are expecting a blog, and that's it:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/endpoint?',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // <= important
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```